# Use AWS issued certificate for a Spring Boot app

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I have an app running on AWS that has got a React JS front-end hosted through S3 and Spring Boot back-end hosted on EC2 instances behind a *load balancer*. I got my SSL certificate for my domain and I use CloudFront to redirect HTTP requests into HTTPS.

My issue is that I can connect through HTTPS to my load balancer, however, my Spring Boot API won't accept HTTPS from the load balancer. Therefore I use HTTP and anytime I send an API call to my backend, my site changes to "*Not Secured*".

Is there a way to use the Amazon issued certificate in my Spring Boot API in order for it to accept HTTPS calls? I have only found tutorials using *self-signed certs* and was wondering if I can use my AWS certificate instead.

If there is a way, could you please provide an example of code I need to insert in my `application.properties` file?

Cheers
Kris

Comment: Are you trying to provide end-to-end encryption, by adding SSL between your Java app and the load balancer? Or are you just trying to get Spring Boot to stop redirecting the user's browser to an HTTP URL?

Comment: Umm in all honesty I just want the browser to stop going from Secure to Not Secure every time I switch from homepage (doesn't call API) to products page that makes an API call to the back-end. This app is for my pure entertainment and will never really hold any sensitive data. As it stands right now, when my front-end calls the API, the https:// bit gets red and crossed out on the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of your question is really confusing, since you don't provide details about what you mean:

> My issue is that I can connect through HTTPS to my load balancer,
> however, my spring-boot API won't accept HTTPS from the load balancer.

Your load balancer should be serving the AWS ACM SSL certificate. You should code your application so that your website makes SSL calls to your API. The load balancer should communicate with your Spring Boot backend server over HTTP, by setting the HTTP protocol and port in the load balancer target group settings.

The traffic flow should look like this:

`Web Browser -> (HTTPS) API call to Load Balancer -> (HTTP) call to backend Spring Boot server`

Comment: Thanks Mark, that is how it is set up right now. But I believe that the part where Load balancer communicates with Spring Boot over HTTP makes my site Not Secure. So I thought that that call should be over HTTPS too. Could it be that it is not the HTTP call between load balancer and spring boot server that makes the site show Not Secure?

Comment: Your web browser has no idea what is happening behind the load balancer. That is not what makes your site show a "not secure" warning.

Comment: Cheers Mark, that is exactly what I needed to hear. Will investigate what makes my site Not Secure. Thanks again for the explanation mate!

Comment: @Kris you should be able to look in your browser's developer console, in the network tab, to see what requests are happening over a non-SSL connection to make your browser show that warning.

Comment: Interesting. Tried copying the load balancer's DNS in the browser and that shows not secure as well. That wasn't the case when I only had the backend set up. I must have adjusted something that is now making the connect unsecure.

Comment: You should have a DNS record setup that points to the load balancer, that matches the domain name in the SSL certificate. And you should be adding `https` to that URL. Just pasting the domain name into a web browser isn't going to be secure by default, especially when you have the load balancer serving both HTTP and HTTPS it sounds like.

Comment: hmm my DNS record `productapp.net` routes traffic to my cloudfront distribution which is set with the origin in my S3 bucket for frontend and alternate domain name `productapp.net`. Certificate is also for `productapp.net`, however, going to `productapp.net/products` calls the load balancer and triggers the Not secure message.

Comment: So you have CloudFront serving the API in front of the load balancer? Honestly, without seeing the results from the browser's network console, when you try going to `https://productapp.net/products` I can only guess what your issue might be.

Comment: If by API it is meant the S3 API then yes. My load balancer is for the back-end servers. I guess the flow would be Route 53 -> CloudFront -> S3 Front end -> Load balancer -> EC2 Auto-Scaling group. CloudFront used to be right before the load balancer but now it sits before S3. My load balancer listener is configured to HTTPS using the domain SLL certificate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223367/discussion-between-mark-b-and-kris).